# datagrid column formatter not working

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I'm using the [jQuery EasyUI datagrid](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datagrid.php) to present some data to the user. I'm trying to color certain data in certain columns of my datagrid based on a certain condition. I did something like this:

```
$('#my_datagrid_id').datagrid({

    columns:[[
        {field:'qty', title:'Quantity', formatter:function(val, row, idx){

            if (val < 25){
                return '<span style="color:red;">('+val+')</span>';
            } else {
                return val;
            }               

        }}
    ]]

});
```

But for some reason, the values of my costs that are less than 25 are not colored red in my datagrid. Any idea why this code is not working please?

Thank you

Comment: alert (val < 25) and check what it is returning

Answer (score 0):

for my assumption, you need to specific the grid column like this

```
{field:'qty', title:'Quantity',editor:{type:'numberbox'}, formatter:function(val, row, idx){
```

I have try this combination and have no problem with it

hope can help you